# How can i customize segment control in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to implement a segmented control. I want to customize it:

- Separate boarder for each item.
- Default segment should be in color
  boarder.
- Segment control should be scroll

How can i achieve like below image?

[image]

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: Why not use collection view with custom cells instead?

Comment: here i'm using segment control for filter purpose. any reference for filter using collection view.

Comment: Filter purpose? Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: Might be this helps to you: https://www.codementor.io/kevinfarst/designing-a-button-bar-style-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift-cg6cf0dok

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are looking for you need to use `UICollectionView` with your custom flow layout.
Here are some examples that you can use or inspire : [TTGTagCollectionView](https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView) - [YNSearch](https://github.com/younatics/YNSearch) - [TagListView](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView)

Comment: is it available in swift 4

Comment: @ParameswaranV `TagListView` is available in swift 4 [Here](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView/tree/swift-4)